# Java HTML parsing library without HTML fixing

Tags: java, html, parsing

I need to parse an HTML document than modify it and save it. The problem is that I want to change only specific elements and rest of the document should stay like it was at the beginning. A lot of libraries like JSoup automatically fixes and improves HTML during parsing and I don't want that. Do you know any libraries without such functionality or with possibility to disable it? Ideally parse method for me should try to parse an HTML document and when something is wrong exception should be raised.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using JDK native DOM support.
You can parse an HTML file to obtain a DOM object. Then modify the DOM object (eventually using XPath to retrieve the elements you want to modify). Finally, serialise the DOM object back into an HTML.

To parse a HTML document you would probably need something like:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document dom = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new FileReader(htmlFile)));
```

Check Document, DocumentBuilder and DocumentBuilderFactory documentation to configure the HTML parsing correctly:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html

Then use the dom to modify all the elements you want and when you've done serialise it back to a HTML document by writing something similar to:

```
  TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
  DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
  FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(htmlFile);
  transformer.transform(source, new StreamResult(writer));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the HTML source exactly how it was (including whitespace, comments, poorly formed XML and newlines etc) then I'm pretty sure your only option is find and replace. You might find that you can solve your problem with a regular expression and some [capturing groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) without actually parsing the HTML.

All other solutions (that I can think of) will parse the HTML into some form of [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) and lose whitespace / newlines and probably comments etc. At the end you'll convert the DOM back into an HTML string but will most likely lose some of the original formatting. Depending on the DOM implementation you may even find that the ordering of attributes has changed (most likely due to use of `java.util.HashMap`).

All DOM parsing solutions (that I can think of) will require that your HTML is properly formed XML. The more lenient parsers will 'fix' the HTML so that it is properly formed XML.